# maximum concurrent connections for ubuntu?

Tags: database, ubuntu, connection

i would like to ask how many concurrent connections can ubuntu handle? i heard that xp a maximum of 10 connections.. i will use it as an OS for my small server and will be using mysql on it..

Answer (score 6):

You are probably making all of the tcp connections from one process and hitting the default limit on number of open files per process.
You can confirm that limit with 'ulimit -a' or 'ulimit -n' at a shell prompt.
You could increase that limit with 'ulimit -n ' or setrlimit() as root or by editing /etc/security/limits.conf .

Also see...

[Increasing the maximum number of tcp/ip connections in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux)
[Is there a limit on number of tcp/ip connections between machines on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760819/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-between-machines-on-linux)