# Websocket client receive RST packet when the number of connections more than 7k

Tags: websocket, tcp, c10k, stress

I use ws(websocket) client(`github.com/gorilla/websocket`, **running on local host**) to stress test ws server which is implemented by java **Netty** (running on remote centos 7.8 host with 2vcpu + 8Gb memory). Only the client start tcp keepalive mechanism.

When the number of connections more than 7k, then client side start to receive RST packet(include new and old connections).

[Wireshark capture package detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfRXw.png)

I have verified the server side's `syn_recv queue` and `accept queue` are idle during testing and no syn packet droped, no listen queue overflowed. So i need help....

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here very succinctly [Is there a limit on number of tcp/ip connections between machines on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760819/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-between-machines-on-linux)

I believe you are running out of listening sockets.
You can use the `ss` command to start identifying this.

Also check /var/log/messages for max-sockets.