# How many requests per seconds can Linux hosting support

Tags: linux, http, webserver, cgi-bin

I am writing network game.
Suppose there are 500 users.
Each user sends one HTTP Get request each 5 seconds.
So I have 100 requests per second.
Is it a big digit?
Ansi C Linux cgi-bin program works on the server side.
Each request reads/writes about 100 byte from 2-3 files.

How many requests can Linux server support?
Can someone recommend me fast Linux hosting?
Thanks!

Comment: This totally depend on your software+network+hardware. Not on linux itself.

Comment: Note that using a `cgi-bin` style program is going to be about the *least* performant solution you can choose, since it requires starting up the program for every individual request.

Comment: Consider using FASTCGI not CGI .... to avoid having lots of processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [limitations of the Linux operating system itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350071/maximum-number-of-concurrent-connections-on-a-single-port-socket-of-server) are in order of several thousand connections at time, but it is less clear how fast they could be serviced. A dedicated not old web server with wiki engine using database backend can easily service about ten requests per second and probably more.