# If I have 10000 connected to my application server running on a linux machine, what should I see if I netstat?

Tags: linux, sockets, tomcat, networking, netstat

I'm trying to understand something. It's networking 101, I'm sure.

Say I have my application server (java, tomcat for the sake of the example, but it doesn't matter if it's really tomcat or not) running on a linux machine.  I have 10000 users connected to that application server. Say it's websockets, so the connections are being maintained.

Does each user get a socket at the operating system level for my java application server to respond directly to them?  Can I see all of these sockets using netstat?

If not, is there some way I can see them?

Comment: 10,000 users won't be hitting all at the exact same moment. you'd only see connections for users who are actually in the middle of an http request.

Comment: So what if it's websockets and maintaining an actual connection that way?  Does this apply?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129212/tcp-two-different-sockets-sharing-a-port

Answer (score 2):

`netstat` will show you all active connections.

IF there are many, better use `netstat -an` (`-n` tells it to not try to use DNS to resolve ip adresses, much faster)

`lsof` ([see this daniel miessler neat presentation](http://danielmiessler.com/study/lsof/)) also have lots of neat informations and is a great help in debugging (connection, but also which file(s) are opened by which pid)

Answer (score 1):

As Websockets are working through a permanent TCP connection, then the answer is yes, you will see all the established connections in netstat.