# how to make a socket server for multiple clients

Tags: java, sql, client, p2p

I have seen a lot of tutorials on client/server chat rooms using sockets, I am trying to create a instant messenger which will allow users (stored in a sql db) to chat with there contacts and groups(also stored on sql db). now I am really puzzled where to start. how would i go about creating a server which can handle peer to peer chat and group chat. I am using a mysql database which will store the user data and contacts list.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started on ServerSocket and ClientSockets for multiple clients you can refer to the below post.
[Two Socket sharing a port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129212/tcp-two-different-sockets-sharing-a-port)

Ideally every client would have only 1 socket connection to the server. To differentiate between your chats you can very simply use a unique identifier which will help differentiate between the different chat types.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so do you mean that ever client would have a socket each which would connect to ONE socket in the server or will the server have to have a socket for each client socket.

Comment: The Server would have 1 `ServerSocket`. Multiple clients (each with a `Socket` of their own) would connect to the same `ServerSocket` in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a multi-threaded socket server, this will accept incoming connections on a loop, and then pass off all operation between that instance of the socket and the client into a separate thread. This will allow you to run multiple client connections at once. [This Page](http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html) goes into great detail about creating both single and multi-threaded chat servers.