# Using same address and port for accepting and connecting in Java

Tags: java, sockets

(This might have been asked a thousand times, but I do not get it straight.)

Suppose I have the following snippet:

```
InetAddress localAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.10");
int localPort = 65000;
InetAddress targetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.20");
int targetPort = 65000;

// Create a new serversocket 
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(localPort, 50, localAddress);
// Wait for an incoming connection...
Socket acceptedSocket = ss.accept();
// Do something with the accepted socket. Possibly in a new thread.

Set up new connection...
Socket socket = new Socket(targetAddress, targetPort, localAddress, localPort);
// Write something to the socket.
```

Now can I use the same address and port for both accepting an incoming connection and connecting to an address? If it can, then how? If not, then why not? According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129212/tcp-two-different-sockets-sharing-a-port), ports can be shared, so it shouldn't be a problem.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can *only* establish a connection by having the connecting socket use the same address and port. (Ignoring the use of multi-homed servers)

A single connection is a unique combination of both the source address+port and destination address+port, so you can have the same destination if you have a different source.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, can you write server program that that contains client connecting to itself? The answer is yes, surely. All integration tests do this running in-process server and connecting to it.