# How to connect with TCP to different hosts from the same source ip and port

Tags: go, tcp

I would like to initiate TCP connections between a process and other processes which are already listening from incoming TCP connections.
I would like to use the same source address (ip-port) for these connections.
I am programming in Go.

I tried to run this code, but the second DialTCP call fails.

```
func main() {

    ourAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:51234")

    otherAddr1, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:51236")
    otherAddr2, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:51237")

    conn1, err1 := net.DialTCP("tcp", ourAddr, otherAddr1)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal("err1: " + err1.Error())
    }
    defer conn1.Close()

    conn2, err2 := net.DialTCP("tcp", ourAddr, otherAddr2) // <- this fails
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal("err2: " + err2.Error())
    }
    defer conn2.Close()

}
```

The error message is: **err2: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:51234->127.0.0.1:51237: bind: address already in use**

(the problem should not be related to the destination processes since two instances of netcat are already listening on the destination addresses)

I also tried using other ports (in case they were still in use) and it failed the same way

Here is my go version:
`go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64`

It seems to me the problem is not related to TCP but to the way I am using the Go library.
What am I doing wrong, and how am I supposed to do?

Comment: https://github.com/libp2p/go-reuseport might help

Comment: This should be possible in TCP in theory but it isn't in practice, because at the C level `bind()` precedes `connect()`. You can't rely on this kind f thing.

Comment: The approach proposed by @SteffenUllrich appears to be what you are looking for. It uses `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` socket options. 

It is important to note that these options are not standardized. From their description, it appears they are used in some very load intensive situations and I wonder if go routines mitigate some of the problems they are solving.

Comment: The approach proposed by  Steffen Ullrich will not work with TCP under any circumstances, for the reason I stated. @MomchilAtanasov

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing is a general one, not related to Go programming language.

To my knowedge, you should not be able to connect to two destinations from the same source IP address and Port. I am pretty sure this is backed up by the message you get.

```
err2: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:51234->127.0.0.1:51237: bind: address already in use
```

It is not complaining about your destination address. It is complaining about the source address `127.0.0.1:51234`. Try to change your source address and see what happens.

---

Edit: It appears that there are socket options `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` that allow that but are non-standardized and appear to be used under verify specific load-intensive scenarios.

It would help to know why you want to achieve such a setup.

---

Addition: There is a stackoverflow question that is related to your problem: [TCP: can two different sockets share a port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129212/tcp-can-two-different-sockets-share-a-port)

Comment: The interleaved data you describe cannot possibly occur.

Comment: @user207421, care to explain a bit? What I was describing was a hypothetical problem if a streaming API were to receive from two streams. In what way is that not possible, buffer size and TCP aside?