# Implementing dynamically updating upvote/downvote

Tags: mysql, architecture, memcached, voting-system

How to implement dynamically updating vote count similar to quora:- Whenever a user upvotes an answer its reflected automatically for every one who is viewing that page.

I am looking for an answer that address following:

- Do we have to keep polling for upvote counts for every answer, If yes
  then how to manage the server load arising because of so many users
  polling for upvotes.
- Or to use websockits/push notifications, how scalable are these?
- How to store the upvote/downvote count in databases/inmemory to support this. How do they control the number of read/writes. My backend database is mysql

The answer I am looking for may not be exactly how quora is doing it, but may be how this can be done using available opensource technologies.

Comment: For polling, use long polling which at least reduces the hits on the server. You have a loop with a delay at the end and drop out of the loop when you find something to report back to the front end (or after a fixed time to stop orphan requests staying for too long). Then the front end processes the data and send the next request.

Comment: Do you only need to update the number of votes or many other things? The amount of data and how frequent the updates -sending/getting data from server is what will determine what technologies/techniques to use.<br/> If it's only the number of votes, then use normal AJAX-101, pass the server an array of posts ids and have it return a JSON object (few kbs) of the new votes counter and with simple jquery update the view, run this every 2 sec with setInterval and have it clear it self so there would be no big memory usage.

Comment: This process can be optimized. If you want to have a real-time data connection to the server, then just upgrade you methods a bit and use node.js. 
If you are anticipating that the amount of data must be updated will increase, then use the same techno similar to facebook/gmail/yahoo chat system "Real Time Messaging Protocol"=>"is a TCP-based protocol which maintains persistent connections and allows low-latency communication. To deliver streams smoothly and transmit as much information as possible, it splits streams into fragments and their size is negotiated dynamically between client/server"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the back-end system details that you need to worry about but the front end. Having connection being open all the time is impractical at any real scale. Instead you want the opposite - to be able to serve and close connection from back-end as fast as you can.

Websockets is a sexy technology, but again, in real world there are [issues with proxies](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers), if you are developing something that should work on a variety of screens (desktop, tablet, mobile) it might became a concern to you. Even good-old long polls might not work through firewalls and proxies.

Here is a good news: I think

> "keep polling for upvote counts for every answer"

is a totally good solution in this case. Consider the following:

- your use-case does not need any **real** real-time updates. There is little harm to see the counter updated a bit later
- for very popular topics you would like to squash multiple up-votes/down-votes into one anyway
- most of the topics will see no up-vote/down-vote traffic at all for days/weeks, so keeping a connection open, waiting for an event that never comes is a waste
- most of the user will never up-vote/down-vote that just came to read a topic, so your read/write ration of topics stats will be greatly skewed toward reads
- network latencies varies hugely across clients, you will see horrible transfer rates for a 100B http responses, while this sluggish client is fetching his response byte-by-byte your precious server connection and what is more importantly - thread on a back end server is busy

Here is what I'd start with:

- have browsers periodically poll for a new topic stat, after the main page loads
- keep your MySQL, keep counters there. Every time there is an up/down vote update the DB
- put Memcached in front of the DB as a write-through cache i.e. every time there is an up/down vote update cache, then update DB. Set explicit expire time for a counter there to be 10-15 minutes . Every time counter is updated expire time is prolongated automatically.
- design these polling http calls to be cacheable by http proxies, set expire and ttl http headers to be 60 sec
- put a reverse proxy([Varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29), [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)) in front of your front end servers, have this proxy do the caching of the said polling calls. These takes care of the second level cache and help free up backend servers threads quicker, see network latencies concern above
- set-up your reverse proxy component to talk to memcached servers **directly** without making a call to the backend server, yes if your can do it with both Varnish and nginx.
- there is no fancy schema for storing such data, it's a simple `inc()/dec()` operation in memcached, note that it's safe from the race condition point of view. It's also a safe atomic operation in MySQL `UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE [...]`

Aggressive multi level caching covers your `read` path: in Memcached and in all http caches along the way, note that these http poll requests will be cached on the [edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) as well.

To take care of the long tail of unpopular topic - make http ttl for such responses reverse proportional to popularity.

A read request will only infrequently gets to the front end server, when http cache expired and memcached does not have it either. If that is still a problem, add memecached servers and increase expire time in memcached across the board.

After you done with that you have all the `reads` taken care of. The only problem you might still have, depending on the scale, is high rate of `writes` i.e. flow of up/down votes. This is where your single MySQL instance might start showing some lags. Fear not - proceed along the old beaten path of sharding your instances, or adding a NoSQL storage just for counters.

Do not use any messaging system unless absolutely necessary or you want an excuse to play with it.

Answer (score 5):

Websockets, Server Sent Events (I think that's what you meant by 'push notifications') and AJAX long polling have the same drawback - they keep underlying TCP connection open for a long time.
So the question is how many open TCP connections can a server handle.
Basically, it depends on its OS, number of file descriptors (a config parameter) and available memory (each open connection reserves a read/write buffers).
[Here's more on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332741/what-is-the-theoretical-maximum-number-of-open-tcp-connections-that-a-modern-lin)

We once tested a possibility to keep 1 million websocket connections open on a single server (Windows 7 x64 with 16Gb of RAM, JVM 1.7 with 8Gb of heap, using [Undertow beta](http://undertow.io/) to serve Web requests). 
Surprisingly, the hardest part was to generate the load on the server )
It managed to hold 1M. But again the server didn't do something useful, just received requests, went through protocol upgrade and kept those connections open.
There was also some number of lost connections, for whatever reason. We didn't investigate. But in production you would also have to ping the server and handle reconnection.

Apart from that, Websockets seem like an overkill here, [SSE still aren't widely adopted.](http://caniuse.com/eventsource)
So I would go with good old AJAX polling, but optimize it as much as possible.
Works everywhere, simple to implement and tweak, no reliance on an external system (I had bad experience with that several times), possibilities for optimization.
For instance, you could group updates for all open articles in a single browser, or adjust update interval according to how popular the article is.
After all it doesn't seem like you need real-time notifications here.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you might be able to use a messaging system like Kafka, or RabbitMQ, or ActiveMQ. Your front end would sent votes to a message channel and receive them with a listener, and you could have a server side piece persist the votes to the db periodically.

You could also accomplish your task by polling your database, and by incre/decre menting a number related to a post via a stored proc... there are a bunch of options here and it depends on how much concurrency you may be facing.

Comment: does messaging systems maintains an active connection to update the listeners? In my case users will access through the web browser and suppose there are too many users wont that put too much pressure on such systems? would I have to increase the size of the cluster to handle this?

Comment: I have not used Kafka, but it appears promising. There is an api for polling the system here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

Kafka scales by adding nodes, and it can handle huge volume. Some pretty big companies are using it

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Powered+By