# Websocket server get killed when receiving many connections

Tags: c++, http, websocket, centos

I'm using [Zaphoyd Websocketpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/tree/master/websocketpp) to creat a websocket server that need to accept very high concurrent connections ( C1M at least) on CentOS.
But the server process always get killed by kernel when the number of connections reached about 63k.
I see this message in dmesg:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 5420 (echo_server) score 382 or sacrifice child
Killed process 5420, UID 10545, (echo_server) total-vm:1488192kB, anon-rss:1467524kB, file-rss:32kB
```

I don't think the kernel will kill the process that only consumes about 1.5GB. So I created a simple program that allocates memory and do some read/write operations. This program was not killed by kernel. It only gets bad_alloc error when memory usage reaches 3.2GB.

I also checked some other parameters but found nothing suspicious:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29712
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 29712
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
10485760
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
1280000
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
1536    0   1280000
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: 63K TCP connections to the same machine?

Comment: Yes, about 64K TCP connections to the same machine. But the process get killed is not client, it's server.

Answer (score 1):

Are those connections created from the same machine?

[What is the theoretical maximum number of open TCP connections that a modern Linux box can have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332741/what-is-the-theoretical-maximum-number-of-open-tcp-connections-that-a-modern-lin)

> If a client has many connections to the same port on the same
>   destination, then three of those fields will be the same - only
>   source_port varies to differentiate the different connections. Ports
>   are 16-bit numbers, therefore the maximum number of connections any
>   given client can have to any given host port is 64K.

Comment: The total number of connections are less than 63K so it's not the 64K limitation. I also tried to make the connections from different host. The result is still the same.