# JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use

Tags: java, spring, redis

i have meet a problem when i use redis in multi-threads environment.
some redis config codes below.

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
    StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(serializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}

private RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(host, port);
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(shardInfo);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setDatabase(db);
    factory.setTimeout(timeOut);
    JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
    config.setMaxTotal(20);
    factory.setPoolConfig(config);
    return factory;
}
```

i execute a brpoplpush operation in multi-threads. some codes below

```
     RedisConnection redisConnection = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        try {
            value = redisConnection.bRPopLPush(5, RWeixinDao.WEIXIN_MSG_KEY.getBytes(), key.getBytes());
        } finally {
            redisConnection.close();
        }
```

and i got some exceptions

`23:35:56.859 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR c.j.n.i.s.impl.MessageProcessorImpl - process weixin message fail.
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at com.jiyu.nowitzki.im.service.impl.MessageProcessorImpl.process(MessageProcessorImpl.java:82)
    at com.jiyu.nowitzki.im.service.impl.MessageProcessorImpl.lambda$run$0(MessageProcessorImpl.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:82)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:159)
    ... 7 common frames omitted`

it says this code is wrong

`RedisConnection redisConnection = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();`

does it cause by i call the close() method? 
anyone could tell me plz... thxs

Comment: You're probably running out of [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

Comment: @mp911de how does it happen? i'm lack of tcp/os knowledge. can you give  more details thanks.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2332741/2067527

Comment: @mp911de thanks a lot. I still can't understand why my redis application could throw the exception. does it cause by the multi-threads?