# How to get actual time TCP request is made and response is received by OS

Tags: python, linux, http, ubuntu, tcp

I'm load testing a server so I have a client spitting out lots of HTTP requests (hundreds, possibly thousands per second).  I want to measure how long it takes for the server to respond.  Currently I'm measuring this response time as follows:

```py
import requests, time

start_time = time.time()
response = requests.get('https://testserver.mydomain.com/service')
response_time = time.time() - start_time
```

I'm worried however that when the client is making too many requests per second, then the http request is not actually sent to the server at `start_time` but rather spends some time kicking around the client machine in some queue or something of that nature.  How can I get a more accurate `start_time`?

(Note that have modified ulimits and [some other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923785/189336) on both the client and server to handle a high number of concurrent requests---my question isn't so much about how to get a system to handle many concurrent requests, but rather about how to measure when the request is actually made).

Answer (score 0):

If your main objective is just to load test the server, you should probably consider using an existing tool for the job, e.g. [ApacheBench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html). For more complicated tests, you could try [Multi-Mechanize](http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/). These tools are specifically designed for load testing purposes and possibly lack in the overhead when compared to libraries like Requests in your example.