# Maximum TCP connections (with different IPs/containers)

Tags: sockets, tcp, docker

I was reading this answer: [Increasing the maximum number of tcp/ip connections in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux)

My setup is as follows. I have multiple containers, each with their own IP, and I communicate to a process inside them through tcp (its all same machine). As such, all the processes use the same port, but have their own unique IP. Does that mean I will *not* run into the tcp limitations described above (since those seem to be port-based?)

```
Controller Process -> container 1 [with unique IP, port X]
                   -> container 2 [with unique IP, port X]
                   -> container 3 [with unique IP, port X]
                   -> container 5 [with unique IP, port X]
```

Apologies if this question is rudimentary phrased, new to some of this stuff. Happy to provide any additional info.

Comment: How would using different 'containers', by which I assume you mean VMs, relieve an FD shortage in the server?

Comment: They are Linux containers, so not VMs. (Docker). I am not sure how it would anything, I'm just explaining that in my setup the limitation is not ports (so theoretically not affected by ip_local_port_range?). As such, I'm curious if the tcp limitation is a port count one or a deeper one (such as fd)