# Increase connect(2) timeout in RestClient / Net::HTTP on AWS Linux

Tags: ruby, sockets, amazon-ec2, net-http

I'm using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to POST to a very slow web service. I'm setting `timeout` to 600 seconds, and I've confirmed that it's being passed down to Net::HTTP's `@read_timeout` and `@open_timeout`.

However, after about two minutes, I get a low-level timeout error, `Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)`:

The relevant part of the backtrace is

```
Operation timed out - connect(2) for [myhost] port [myport]
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `call'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `timeout'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rest-client-2.0.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:766:in `transmit'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rest-client-2.0.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:215:in `execute'
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rest-client-2.0.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in `execute'
```

It looks like the line of code throwing the error is

```
TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)
```

It seems as though the underlying `connect(2)` system call has a timeout of about two minutes, and the timeout parameters passed to Net::HTTP can only shorten that, not lengthen it. Is there a way to modify the socket parameters to set a longer timeout?

**Edited to add:** This only appears to be a problem on our AWS Linux servers -- on my MacOS development machine, the ten-minute timeout works. I assume the default `connect()` timeout is longer on MacOS/BSD, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you could just increase the [`tcp_syn_retries`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) configuration updating the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries` file. Reference [here](http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout).

If if doesn't work, I think you will need to activate the `SO_KEEPALIVE` or `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` options. But probably there is no interface for that in `rest-client`.

So maybe you'll need to make a fork or create the [`Socket`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) and [`Socket::Option`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket/Option.html) by yourself.

Mike Perham wrote about it in his [blog](http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/03/15/socket-timeouts-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are gettin out of sockets. The sockets need some time before be available again, if you are opening to many connections in a short period of time, this may be the problem.

Check `ulimit -n` to check the maximum number of opened file descriptors. Remember that a socket is a file, you need to change that to allow to open more sockets. To change the maximum number of opened files do `sudo ulimit -n 1000000`.

For more information, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux).

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of a `2m` limitation, but AWS NATs have a [`350s` timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout). We had this same issue with our `sidekiq` instances where even though we had `http_read_timeout` set to `15m` (for a Lambda invocation), even though the lambda completed in less than `15m` we still received this error.

To fix, we did two things:

- set the [`tcp_keepalive_time` setting](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html) to `< 350s`
- set the `SO_KEEPALIVE` on all sockets to be enabled

For *us*, this was the AWS SDK using `Net::HTTP`, which does *not* set this option. Because we did not see a way to override the HTTP adapter for the AWS v3 SDK, we were relegated to this in an initializer:

```rb
module KeepAliveAwareNetHttp
  def on_connect
    @socket.io.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    super
  end
end

Net::HTTP.prepend(KeepAliveAwareNetHttp)
```

In order to verify this on your server (to see if there are any TCP sockets that have this set) you can run `ss -te`. If there is a socket that has this enabled, it'll look something like this:

```
ESTAB   0         0                171.190.0.6:53254        100.80.12.28:5432     timer:(keepalive,3min11sec,0) ino:113741 sk:90 <->
```

The time indicates how much time is remaining before it will send the next keep-alive packet.