# NetTimeout when using Ruby AWS SDK to invoke a synchronous Lambda in threads

Tags: ruby, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk-ruby

This has got me really stumped and hope that someone might have some insight on this.
We are using Ruby and the AWS SDK to invoke a AWS Lambda synchronously.  The time it take for the Lambda to complete is "usually" no more than 7 minutes.

The timeout defined in the AWS console for our Lambda is 600 seconds (10 minutes)
The configuration we have AWS Lambda client object is :

```
{
  http_read_timeout: 600,
  max_attempts: 1,
  retry_limit: 0
}
```

We have a requirement that we need to invoke this Lambda multiple times in threads.  Each thread would use a different AWS Lambda Client object (but with the same above configuration) and a different event payload passed into it upon invocation.  Our program waits for all the thread(s) doing the invocation to complete.

Locally, from our computers this works very reliably.  However, when our program is run within ECS then we get NET::Timeout TCP socket errors.  The Lambda will invoke X times.  The code in the Lambda will succeed.  But the AWS Lambda client in the thread(s) doing the invocation - reach the 600 timeout without receiving the response from the Lambda and fail with the NET::Timeout TCP error.

We *could* change our design such that:

- Invoke the Lambda asynchronously N times.
- Each invocation then publish the result in the form of an AWS SNS topic.
- An AWS SQS queue is subscribed to the topic and the incoming messages go onto the queue
- Our program then polls the SQS queue, retrieving the messages and completing the feedback loop.

But that is not a trivial re-design and refactor.  Possibly a 6 days work of dev/test - which we don't have.

But I would be v.grateful to anyone whom has any valuable insight into this problem.  Be good to have a dialogue and share some ideas.

Thank you kindly guys!

- Our approach and program works reliably locally from our computers.
- The problem is reproduced when our program is run as a micro service in ECS.
- I intend to test this locally in Docker container and see what happens.  I wonder if this related to a limitation of sockets available within a Docker container ?

Answer (score 0):

We think we cracked this.  Hopefully, if anyone has a similar problem, hopefully this will help them out.

The problem was client side.  Specifically in the alpine docker container OS.  We needed to

a). Set the tcp_keepalive_time = 300

https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

b). Set the tcp_syn_retries = 8

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html
http://willbryant.net/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout

We found that our program in the ECS container was successfully sending an API call to the AWS Lambda API.  The Lambda API received it, triggered the Lambda.  But socket on the client-side (our ECS container) was being closed.  However, our app - was completely unaware of this.

We also had to monkey patch the `Net::HTTP` as described in [Increase connect(2) timeout in RestClient / Net::HTTP on AWS Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600348/increase-connect2-timeout-in-restclient-nethttp-on-aws-linux)

Comment: I think what solved your problem is the `Set the tcp_syn_retries = 8` secifically. Every retry adds expential time for retrys  (8 = 190s). Your connection was proably failing before the TCP connection was alive.

Answer (score -1):

> Locally, from our computers this works very reliably. However, when our program is run within ECS then we get NET::Timeout TCP socket errors. The Lambda will invoke X times.

If it still is able to invoke the Lambda function from ECS but it times out perhaps something somewhere in the networking between them is timing it out, something with ECS, load balancer, proxy, something like that?  May be worth investigating.

Tough to know without all the details but in general I would probably go for an async design as it will be able to scale and handle failures better.  Instead of calling the Lambda function async directly, your threads could push messages to an SQS queue which the Lambda function reads from.

Comment: Hi @rr3tt.  Thank you for your response.  We believe we've found a possible cause.   We were discussing with AWS support.  We send a request from our client app to AWS Lambda service API and request it to invoke our Lambda function. The request does reach the target API, but it takes longer than the keep alive duration on the client OS, or the network in between. Since the socket has been shut down in a lower level, the app doesn't have any idea, and still waits for the response, but there is no response coming back.  We are suspecting OS config in the Alpine container running in ECS.

Comment: Here is some info about TCP keep alive https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html. and something else I found on Stack overflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600348/increase-connect2-timeout-in-restclient-nethttp-on-aws-linux.

Comment: Indeed a Async design is worth thinking about.  The ECS micro service pushes to "request" SQS.  The SQS is hooked into the Lambda's as a stream and the Lambda invocation then publishes the result to an SNS topic.  A "response" SQS is subscribed to the SNS topic.  The ECS program is then pushing onto the "resquest" SQS and polling from the "response" SQS.  Thus completely de-coupled away from the Lambda.  Pub-Sub design.  That I think would be scaleable design.

Comment: Currently, we are trying the changing the TCP keepalive kernel config in the Docker container. I shall keep this thread open and post back any progress.  But it might end up we refactor our design.  Perhaps, not massive - because it's just putting an SQS queue(s) and SNS topic in-between the ECS program and the Lambda

Comment: Btw - we proved it was timing based.  Because the Lambda is responsible for taking  an EC2 instance ID as its event payload.  De-registrating from a Target Group attached to an ALB.  Then shutting the instance down.  If the Target Group's de-registration delay is 300 seconds = We reproduce the problem.  If the Target Group de-registration delay is 150 seconds = We don't reproduce the problem.