# Creating many Sockets in ZMQ - too many files error

Tags: zeromq

I am trying to create sockets with **`inproc://`** transport class from the same context in C.

I can create 2036 sockets, when I try to create more `zmq_socket()` returns **`NULL`** and the `zmq_errno` says 24 `'Too many open files'`.

How can I create more than 2036 sockets? Especially as `inproc` forces me to use only one context.

There are several things I don't understand:
- the sockets are eventually turned to `inproc`, why does it take up files?
- Increasing **`ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS`** does not help, the system file limit appears to be the limiting factor
- I am unable to increase the file limit with **`ulimit`** on my Mac, no workaround helped.

// the code is actually in cython and can be found here:

https://github.com/DavoudTaghawiNejad/ABsinthCE

Answer (score 1):

Use **`zmq_ctx_set()`**:

```
zmq_ctx_set (context, ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS, 256);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution is multi-fold complex:

**`inproc`** does not force you to have a common `Context()` instance, but it is handy to have one, as the signalling / messaging goes without any data-transfers, just by Zero-copy, pointer manipulations for in-RAM blocks of memory, which is extremely fast.

I started to assemble ZeroMQ-related facts about having some 70.000 ~ 200.000 file-descriptors available for "sockets", as supported by O/S kernel settings, but your published aims are higher. **Much higher.**

Given your git-published Multi-agent ABCE Project paper refers to nanosecond shaving, HPC-domain grade solution to have *( cit. / emphasis added: )*

> the whopping **number of 1.073.545.225, many more agents** than fit into the memory of even the most sophisticated supercomputer, some small hundreds of thousands of file-descriptors are not much worth spending time with.

Your Project faces multiple troubles at the same time.

Let's peel the problem layers off, step by step:

---

### File Descriptors (FD) -- Linux O/S level -- System-wide Limits:

To see the actual as-is state:

edit **`/etc/sysctl.conf`** file

```
# vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append a config directive as follows:

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

Save and close the file.

Users need to log out and log back in again to changes take effect or just type the following command:

```
# sysctl -p
```

Verify your settings with command:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

---

### ( Max ) User-specific File Descriptors (FD) Limits:

Each user has additionally a set of `( soft-limit, hard-limit )`:

```
# su - ABsinthCE
$ ulimit -Hn
$ ulimit -Sn
```

However, you can limit your **`ABsinthCE`** user ( or any other ) to any specific limits by editing **`/etc/security/limits.conf`** file, enter:

```
# vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Where you set `ABsinthCE` user the respective soft- and hard-limit as needed:

```
ABsinthCE soft nofile 123456
ABsinthCE hard nofile 234567
```

All that is not for free - each file descriptor takes up some kernel memory, so at some point you may and you will exhaust it. A few hundred thousands file descriptors are not trouble for server deployments, where event-based ( epoll on Linux ) server architectures are used. **But simply straight forget to try to grow this anywhere near the said 1.073.545.225 level.**

---

### Today,
one can have a private HPC machine ( not a Cloud illusion ) with ~ 50-500 TB RAM.

But still, the multi-agent Project application architecture ought be re-defined, not to fail on extreme resources allocations ( just due to a forgiving syntax simplicity ).

Professional Multi-Agent simulators are right due to extreme scaling very, VERY CONSERVATIVE on per-Agent instance resource-locking.

So the best results are to be expected ( both performance-wise and latency-wise ) when using direct memory-mapped operations. ZeroMQ **`inproc://`** transport-class is fine and does not require a `Context()` instance to allocate IO-thread ( as there is no data-pump at all, if using just `inproc://` transport-class ), which is very efficient for a fast prototyping phase. The same approach will become risky for growing the scales much higher towards the levels expected in production.

Latency-shaving and accelerated-time simulator operations throughput scaling is the next set of targets, for raising both the Multi-Agent based simulations static scales and increasing the simulator performance.

---

### For a serious nanoseconds hunting
follow the excellent Bloomberg's guru, John Lakos, insights on HPC.

Either pre-allocate ( as a common Best Practice in RTOS domain) and do not allocate at all, or follow [**John's fabulous testing-supported insights** presented on ACCU 2017.](https://youtu.be/d1DpVR0tw0U)

Comment: If you haven't received a reply please send me an email again. Put stackoverflow into the subject line. Thanks Davoud @user3666197

Answer (score 1):

You can change these using **`sysctl`** ( tried on Yosemite and El Capitan ), but the problem is what to change.  Here is a post on this topic:   [Increasing the maximum number of tcp/ip connections in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux)

That's on Linux, and the Mac is based on BSD 4.x, but man pages for `sysctl` on BSD are available online.

**Note:** `sysctl` is a private interface on iOS.