# Unable to create million socket connection in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, c10k

I have the following bash-function to add static-ip

```
function add_ip_addr() {

    for i in {100..200} 
    do
    
        ipaddr="100.100.100."$i
        command="ip addr add "$ipaddr" dev eth0"
        echo $command
        $($command)
    
    done

}
```

And then I have the following Python3-application to create 1M socket connection

```
import socket

n = 0
sockSet = set()

try :

    for I in range(100, 200):

        ipaddr = "100.100.100." + str(I)
        print("\rProcessing", ipaddr, end="")
        for port in range(10000, 20000):

            s1=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s1.bind((ipaddr, port))
            sockSet.add(s1)
            n+=1

except OSError as ex:

    # Too many open files in system
    if ex.errno == 23: 
        print("\n"+str(n))
```

But I always get `Too many open files in system` exception with the following ouput

```
root@c8c1c6a106c2:~/programs/python# python3 socket-limit.py
Processing 100.100.100.163
630730
root@c8c1c6a106c2:~/programs/python#
```

The ulimit values are as shown below

```
root@c8c1c6a106c2:~/programs/python# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 24682
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 82000
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
root@c8c1c6a106c2:~/programs/python#
```

The `/etc/sysctl.conf` values are as shown below

```
root@c8c1c6a106c2:~/programs/python# tail -6 /etc/sysctl.conf

 fs.file-max = 1048576
 fs.nr_open = 1048576
 net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
 net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576

root@c8c1c6a106c2:~/programs/python#
```

What other change do I have to do to achieve 1 million socket connection ?

Comment: Does this help [Increasing the maximum number of TCP/IP connections in Linux
[Increasing the maximum number of TCP/IP connections in Linux
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux)