# Determining the correct connection count with memcached

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, memcached

A memcached v1.6.21 setup on ubuntu has `maxbytes = 3GB` and `maxconns=1024`. When the server recevies about 600-800 GET requests/sec, it works fine. If this reaches roughly 1000 req/sec, the server refuses connections (as expected). These requests are coming from other servers in the same AWS region using TCP.

1. If I increase `maxconns` to `4096`, the problem stays the same i.e. connections still get refused around 1000/sec. The `stats settings` shows the increased value but the memcached setup still saturates around 1000.
2. The `total_connections` is increasing at the expected rate but `curr_connections` is much smaller at any instance (about 10-20). This contradicts 1 above.
3. The `listen_disabled_num` is always 0 (i.e. total connections haven't exceeded the limit) - which contradicts 1 above.

I'm confused about 1, 2 & 3 above.

Comment: You may want to review the info in this page, in case it's the kernel behaviour which is providing the limit...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux